# Moving MMC snap-in from VS2008 to 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, gac, mmc, mmc3

This is not so much a question but rather a comment since I've found the answer already.

Problem:
I was moving a VS2008 project to VS2010, which uses the Microsoft.ManagementConsole namespace. The reference of the project targeted the DLL registered in the GAC, namely the file `C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ManagementConsole\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.ManagementConsole.dll`. However VS2010 did not accept the reference anymore, even though I checked that the DLL was still in the GAC with the command `gacutil /l`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
On [MSDN: How-To Create a Hello World Snap-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692759.aspx) I found a hint in a comment. Instead of linking the DLL in the GAC, I'd rather link the original DLL in the folder `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\mmc\v3.0\microsoft.managementconsole.dll`. Builds like a charm.

Hope this helps somebody with the same problem!